# Visual Studio 11 and WebDAV?

Tags: webdav, visual-studio-2012

I've been googling, but cannot seem to find a straight-up answer.

Does anyone know if Visual Studio 11 brings the support for connecting to IIS 7/7.5 through WebDAV protocol which was lacking in Studio 2010?

Comment: Do you need source files being accessed via WebDAV or you need capability to connect to WebDAV from your code?

Comment: Looking, hoping, for the ability to connect, develop and publish via the WebDAV method on a Windows 2008 R2 server, where FPSE is no longer included. I know FPSE can be purchased, but that's not always easily doable when working with numerous clients in numerous industries. So I'm hoping we'll be able to connect and develop with the new included functionality in IIS 7.5 without needing to purchase and install other stuff.